# How to create custom button in the admin panel form?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, adminform, action, custom-button

[image]

I want to create custom button besides Update Quantity with an custom action where when you click on it, it makes the Quantity to refund column as zero on credit memo page. How can we create that? Thanks in advance!